# How to add numbering to author-year bibliography / how to modify .bst style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, numbering

I would like to to get the Bibliography list in the form of:

> [1] Author. (Year). Title. Journal Volume: PageFrom-PageTo

I think it might be sufficient to slightly modify (if such a style already exist, please share a link) e.g. the style `model5-names.bst` ([can be found here](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle)) to add numbers to the listing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: By indenting a line of code by four [4] spaces, you can get it to be offset/highlighted. A comment/question: It appears that the style file `model5-names.bst` implements some author-year citation method, which doesn't show a number. Why would you wish to prefix the entries in the references section with numbers -- especially as the numbers won't correspond to anything meaningful in the body of the document itself.

Comment: `Why would you wish to prefix the entries in the references section with numbers.`

To help in navigation (it is faster to point to a number than to find a single line of text (at least if it is printed out)). Also to keep a track how many references were used

Comment: Perhaps `model6-num-names.bst` might be more appropriate. But from that particular style would need these changes: 1) sort the bibliography in alphabetical order 2) change the style of the citation from 
`1. Author. Title. Journal Year; Volume: PageFrom-Pageto.` to `1) Author. (Year). Title. Journal Volume: PageFrom-PageTo`